# Google text to speech api setVoice() not available

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

The documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html  has a method setVoice() where we can set a voice object.

But when I create a TextToSpeech object in my application, I dont get the method setVoice() .

```
TextToSpeech tts = tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US); // I get this method
int result1 = tts.setVoice(); // I dont get this method.
```

Comment: What is the API level you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**setLanguage** was added in API level 4 but **setVoice** was added in API level 21. Make sure you are using API level 21 or above to use **setVoice**.

Comment: Can I set a custom voice in the API? Why is this setVoice() used?

Comment: Whatever voice is there in your phone's Text to Speech engine, you can set it. First you need to get all the available voices by using getVoices and then you can set a voice from the list by using setVoice. check getVoices doc - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getVoices()

Comment: If you need some different kind of voice other than what are provided by your Android default Text to Speech engine, there are other third party APIs

Comment: I want to record users voice and use that voice to read out other text. Is this possible? If so can you suggest any 3rd party libraries if any?

Comment: The way you are saying is not possible. The sentence (in the selected voice) has to come after being processed by a Text to Speech engine.